# What is this mold and why does it keep coming back?

Tags: mold, trim, carpet

This mold-like substance has been growing onto my carpet from the baseboard. I had the carpet cut out and replaced and also sprayed and scraped up the mold on the wood. I came home last night to see it coming back.

It doesn't feel like mold at all, it almost feels like spilled wax. Is it dangerous? How do I get rid of it permanently?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked for insects? I can't really tell from the picture, but it could be a termite tunnel.

Comment: Some molds are slimy and not the usual dry.  Is there any plumbing nearby?  A/C condensate lines, bathrooms above and beside?

Comment: Is there moisture there?